# JSF DataTable value get from method

Tags: jsf, datatable

Can I get value of DataTable in JSF from method that will return a list of objects instead of getting from getter of an attribute?
**FilmBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "filmBean")
@SessionScoped
public class FilmBean
{
    private List<Film> filmList;
    private final Helper helper;
    public FilmBean()
    {
        helper = new Helper();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        filmList = helper.getFilmTitles(0, 100);
    }

    public List getFilmTitles()
    {
        return helper.getFilmTitles(0, 100);
    }

    public List getFilmList()
    {
        return filmList;
    }
}
```

**jsf.xhtml**

```
<h:body>
<h:dataTable value = "#{filmBean.filmList}" var = "film">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name = "header">Film Title</f:facet>                   
                #{film.title}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name = "header">Release Year</f:facet>
                #{film.releaseYear}
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:body>
```

The code above works perfectly until I change `value = "#{filmBean.filmList}"` to `value = "#{filmBean.getFilmTitles()}"` I will get error:

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported
```

But they are both return the list, why is this happen? It looks like it calls the method several time.

Comment: `org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported` is not a problem of web layer (JSF or otherwise). It is related to transaction demarcation on the persistence layer. It is likely that you are trying to begin a database transaction without fully completing the previous transaction already running. This goes to a further abstract layer, Hibernate / JPA.

Comment: @Tiny this is why I say `getFilmTitles()` method has been called several time. And why is this happend?

Comment: Getters should **never** do real work!. And an additional suggestion: read all Q/A with at least 30 upvotes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf?sort=votes. Lots of basic knowledge to gain or at least know Q/A exists in a certain direction. And also take a look at https://jsf.zeef.com